# Python logging does not log pd.info()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logging

```
import logging
import pandas as pd

logger = logging.getLogger('train')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Data
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

logger.info(type(df))
logger.info(df.info())
.
.
.
<other_processes>
.
```

The above code outputs:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
None
.
.
.
```

And at the end of the logs (after all other processes), it also outputs:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Name    4 non-null object
Age     4 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 144.0+ bytes
```

Why does it print `None` when I try to log df.info()? How can I get df.info() at the intended location in my logs?

Comment: `df.info()` prints the info it does not return it, it returns `None`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change buffer parameter in [`DataFrame.info`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) to `StringIO` for text with `.getvalue()`:

```
from io import StringIO
buf = StringIO()
df.info(buf=buf)

logger.info(type(df))    
logger.info(buf.getvalue())
```

Comment: I have another dataframe, df2 which I want to log at a later stage. If I use same buf, it prints both df.info() and df2.info(). How can I clear buf once it is logged?

Comment: @loadbox - then is possible use `buf1= StringIO()` `buf2= StringIO()` `df.info(buf=buf1)` `df.info(buf=buf2)` `logger.info(buf1.getvalue())` `logger.info(buf2.getvalue())`

Comment: This works but I'm unclear on how to clear the buffer? `buf.close()` is really closing it, while I would be happy to flushing the content. `buf.flush()` does not seem to work :(